# Ionic 3: command "ionic build --prod" return with Metadata version mismatch for module error

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, npm, ionic3

While a regular dev build works, the `--prod` returns the following issue:

```
Metadata version mismatch for module /Users/Jem/Desktop/psy-app/node_modules/@angular/cdk/coercion/typings/index.d.ts, found version 4, expected 3
```

I suppose it has to do with my `package.json` yet I can't solve it by manually modifying the versions to latest ones.

My process is probably wrong. How should I approach this?

In case it gives a hint, here goes my `package.json`

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/cdk": "^5.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/core": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/forms": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/http": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.1.3",
    "@ionic-native/core": "3.12.1",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "3.12.1",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "3.12.1",
    "@ionic/cloud-angular": "^0.12.0",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.0.1",
    "angular-svg-round-progressbar": "^1.2.1",
    "cordova-android": "^6.4.0",
    "cordova-plugin-console": "^1.0.5",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^1.1.7",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^4.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.1",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
    "firebase": "^4.8.0",
    "ionic-angular": "3.9.2",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard": "^2.2.1",
    "ionic2-auto-complete": "^1.5.2-release",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "ng2-nvd3": "^2.0.0-rc3",
    "promise-polyfill": "^6.1.0",
    "rxjs": "5.4.0",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "1.3.7",
    "ionic": "3.19.1",
    "typescript": "2.3.3"
  },
  "cordovaPlugins": [
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist",
    "cordova-plugin-console",
    "cordova-plugin-device",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard"
  ],
  "cordovaPlatforms": [],
  "description": "bipol: An Ionic project",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-console": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "ionic-plugin-keyboard": {}
    },
    "platforms": [
      "android"
    ]
  }
```